# Angular2 directive selector syntax

Tags: angular

I want to create directive in Angular2 for custom event "rowclick": `<tr (rowclick)="onRowClicked(item)"></tr>`. Event will respond to clicks on row, but filters out clicks on links and buttons inside row cells.

Directive declaration:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[(rowclick)]',
    events: ['rowclick'],
    host: { '(click)': 'onClick($event)' }
})
```

I have a problem to write directive selector, which targets (rowclick) property. I tried `[rowclick]`, `[(rowclick)]`, `[\\(rowclick\\)]`. None of them works.

How should I write selector to target `(rowclick)` attribute on `tr` element?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be confusing as `(event)` syntax is used to bind to events. 
You can try to define a attribute on the `tr` or use `tr` itself as a selector

`selector: '[special]'   // <tr special>...</tr>`

or

`selector:'tr'`